# Check if my internationalized string in properties file is being used in java code

Tags: java, eclipse, internationalization

I have a java project which has i18n-resource.properties file . In this file I am defining the text to be displayed in various error scenarios. The issue I am facing is that I want to check where each of this is being used without manually going through each class.I am doing development through eclipse.

Is there a plugin of some sort that can do the searches and let me know which string is used in which all places and if there are any that are not being used.

Essentially help me manage i18n-resource.properties file

Comment: Eclipse has a find in files feature. But you can't guarantee that the keys aren't dynamically generated from the code, so not finding the full key doesn't guarantee that the key is unused at runtime. For example, a search for `"foo.bar.baz"` wouldn't find the key if it's used as `"foo.bar" + suffix`, where suffix contains "baz".

Comment: Besides file search, `Ctrl` + hover on the property key.